# Changing style inside jQuery selector dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a div and I am trying to display a text with bold font as follows:

```
$('#div').text("data between "+ fromdate + "to" + todate).css({'text-align':'centre'});
```

How do I display only "fromdate" and "todate" in bold font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.html()`, and wrap the text in `<b>` (if it is presentational) or `<strong>` tags:

```
$('#div')
    .html("data between <b>" + fromdate + "</b> to <b>" + todate + "</b>")
    .css("text-align", "center");
```

And `centre` should be `center`.

Answer (score 2):

set as `html` then assign and `filter` as class, finally set the `css` to the filtered result

```
$('#div').html("data between <span class='bold'>"+ fromdate + "</span>to<span class='bold'>" + todate + "</span>").css({'text-align':'center'}).filter( ".bold" ).css( "font-weight", "bold" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this.

```js
$('#div').html("data between "+ "YourText1" + "to" + "YourText2").css('text-align','center');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```